# where the heck is org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask?

Tags: java, hibernate, ant, task

Where the heck do I get  org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask ? I can't seem to find a .jar file that contains it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Download Hibernate Tools - it's in hibernate-tools.jar located in plugins\org.hibernate.eclipse_3.2.4.CR2-R200901280154\lib\tools

Comment: Now it can't find org.apache.tools.ant.Task .... [[SCREAM!!!]] time for another question :/

Comment: As of version 3.3.1 it is located in plugins\org.hibernate.eclipse_3.3.1.v201006011046R-H111-GA\lib\tools

Comment: How did you know this location? Is it documented somewhere ?

Comment: For hibernate 4.3, I found the tools only here, by googling for them http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-tools/4.3.1.Final

Answer (score 1):

I got the latest (hibernate 4) version of `hibernate-tools.jar` (`hibernate-tools-4.3.1.Final.jar`) like this:

- Get the jar for Hibernate tools v. 4.3.1:

  - Dowload JBossTools 4.3.0
  - from http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/mars/4.3.0.Final.html#zips
  - choose "Update site" download from the "Artifacts" tab
  - the jar is in `jbosstools-4.3.0.Final-updatesite-core\plugins\org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.v_4_3_5.0.0.Final-v20150924-2221-B39.jar\lib`in the unpacked zip

Answer (score 0):

I remember finding it in the jars extracted in the workspace by the Hibernate Tools Eclipse plugin.